# Format XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, simpledateformat, gregorian-calendar

Below is my code

```
GregorianCalendar gregory=new GregorianCalendar();
gregory.setTime(new Date());
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar=DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregory);
System.out.println(xmlGregorianCalendar.toString());
```

When I am printing SOP in last line of above code am getting output like

```
2016-07-28T15:25:47.064+05:30
```

But  Iam trying to get output as

```
2016-07-28+05:30
```

I have tried different formatters but no luck.

Any suggestions will be much helpfull for me

Atleast can we get this format using SimpleDateFormat?

By using simpledateformat iam able to get "2016-07-29+0530". Can you please let me know if we can bring ":" in between "05" and "30". My code below

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddZ");
```

In Java version 7 and 8 it is possible to get by using below

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddXXX");
```

but not sure in java 6 version

Comment: That makes no sence. datepart with timezone?!

Comment: By using simpledateformat iam able to get "2016-07-29+0530". Can you please let me know if we can bring ":" in between "05" and "30". My code below DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddZ"); @Jens

Comment: @Jens It makes sense because your start of day is different by changing the timezone offset. Having 01:00 in one timezone maybe 23:00 in another and you have a different day as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to rebuild the JDK7 functionality. You have to know that the new ***XXX*** calculation is based on the already available fields of the *Calendar* class.
They take the ***Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET*** and the ***Calendar.DST_OFFSET*** and go from there like this:

```
    int totalOffset = calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //handle zero offset
    if (totalOffset == 0) {
        sb.append('Z');
    }

    //convert to minutes because timezones are minute based
    totalOffset = totalOffset / 60000;
    char prefix = '-';
    if (totalOffset >= 0) {
        prefix = '+';
    }
    sb.append(prefix);

    //if negative offset, invert now
    totalOffset = Math.abs(totalOffset);

    sb.append(String.format("%02d", (totalOffset / 60)));
    sb.append(':');
    sb.append(String.format("%02d", (totalOffset % 60)));

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

I hope this snippet helps you to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? Note i did not use Gregorian not sure if you wanted specific of Gregorian Calender in which case you will have to change a bit.

```
ZoneOffset myOffset = ZonedDateTime.now().getOffset();
System.out.println("ZoneOffset is " + myOffset.getId());
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(currentDate + myOffset.getId());
```

This prints :

ZoneOffset is +05:30

2016-07-29+05:30

Comment: Unfortunately there is no ZoneOffset in Java 6 version.  I would have used XXX only if i have to use java 8, but that is not the case.